# How to use Tensorflow Object Detection API for Android to detect static images(captured or from the gallery)?

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have been following the android example from the Tensorflow repository. But the example for TF Detect shows how to detect images in real time. So how do I convert it so that it detects static images.